# Calculating distance between two objects viewed from an angle

Tags: optics, distance, camera

I'm trying to determine the location of this vehicles rear bumper and the front edge of the white road marker. I can't tell if the vehicle is before, at the edge, or just ahead of the marker.

The length of the white marker is exactly 3ft.

[image]

(untouched photo)
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QamnL.png)

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be about physics.

Comment: What's more suitable?

Comment: I'm not really sure that there's a site in the SE network that might suit your needs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about photogrammetry

Comment: indulge me :-D, @Jim

Answer (score 1):

You will need at least three pictures from three different angles to be able to compute their absolute values.

Comment: Why do you believe it's ahead and not at the edge?

Comment: Not if he knew the distance from the camera to the white line; then he would only need 2 cameras.

Comment: yOU ARE CORRECT, I made a wrong assumption, so  I edited the answer and left the part that I do know is true. Actually, a new dell tablet is coming at the end of the year whoc has three cameras exactly for that purpose, triangulate the image from the three differt images and calculate the absolute legnths of objects in any part of the picture at whatever angle they appear.

Comment: he didnt say he knew that information